# Where should I install the kickstand?

Tags: kickstand

I am newbie for cycling. I plan to install a kickstand. But where should I install it? In the center of the bike or on the back side? I don't know the technical terms, so you may get my question from the picture.

I mean the center is

[image]

I mean back side is

[image]

Comment: I vote for nowhere.

Comment: It's hard to tell from your pictures but it looks like your bike is capable of taking a kickstand behind the seat tube. I think i can see a plate welded across the gap between the chain stays and if that has a hole in it for a bolt its's a good place. I've now got a double kickstand mounted there - the bike doesn't lean on it. Almost essential if you're solo with a baby in a seat and there are plenty of other reasons why you might want a kickstand of some sort on a practical bike. Do check it doesn't interfere with anything but don't worry about people saying apps them completely.

Comment: Wherever you can.  Some frames are designed for kickstands behind the bottom bracket, some tolerate them, some will totally reject them.  Similarly, some frames are well set up, in terms of the position and spacing (and strength!) of the rear stays, for a kickstand there, others aren't.

Answer (score 8):

Nowhere is a good option. A bike can't fall over if its leaned on the ground, and in many cases you can lean a bike against a post or a tree if it needs to be kept upright.

On a more serious note, kickstands can [crush bicycle tubes](http://surlybikes.com/info_hole/spew/kickstands_on_long_haul_truckers) or [can interfere with the crank](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/gloss_i-k.html) or some other moving part if something goes wrong. Some frames are designed with kickstands in mind and have some reinforcements for kickstand installation. From this perspective, something like a Click-stand (like a folding tenting pole which can be used as a bike stand) is preferable.

If you insist on having a kickstand, check the bike's manual to see if theres a recommended spot. If not, a rear one is preferable for the interference reason, but you're more likely to find a center one legged kickstand easier, which is the one you'll probably install.

Comment: +1 I had a rear kickstand for years which I thought was useful. Eventually it broke and I found I didn't need it at all. If you do get one, a rear stand doesn't get in the way of the pedals when it's down.

Comment: @WayneJohnston, counterpoint for a center stand:  http://www.amazon.com/dp/B000FR33ZM/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pd_nS_ttl?_encoding=UTF8&colid=12ZTO1NIUOH9G&coliid=I20YRWR3BWJEJX&psc=1  I have these on 2 bikes.  They work great for dealing with trailer and pannier loads.  I do admit though that it rubs the tire on my commuter bike, but only because the chain-stays could be longer.

Comment: @BPugh: good point. A better quality centre stand that doesn't interfere with the pedals is also a good choice and will be more stable.